# Error while running Flask App on Amazon ElasticBean Stalk

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, flask

BTW: apppack is my folder where i have views,models,config file exsist.

I'm working on a Flask web app (API for simple registration and login).

#### application.py:

```
from os import environ
from apppack.models import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I also have a `manage.py` file which simply makes db and table structure.
What I have done is that I have manually taken the dump export from pgAdmin (`postgresql`) and imported that to Amazon RDS (Postgres).

And taken the correct connection string and passed it to config.py file.
Now Initially my app on local server started from application.py->manage.py->views.py or models.py.

But when I deployed it to AWS BeanStalk it gave the log.

> failed to import from line 2 in application.py

But since its importing `manage.py` I don't want to even go to that file I want simply the to host simple API that is written in views and models.py when it runs it simply start hosting logging in and register and DB is connected like a string just like locally done.

#### model.py:

```
import jwt
import datetime
import app, db, bcrypt
import config


class User(db.Model):
    """ User Model for storing user related details """
    __tablename__ = "ConfuUsers"

    #__abstract__ = True
    #id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


    def __init__(self, email, password, admin=False):
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
            password, app.config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')
        ).decode()
        self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.admin = admin

    def encode_auth_token(self, user_id):
        """
        Generates the Auth Token
        :return: string
        """
        try:
            payload = {
                'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=500),
                'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                'sub': user_id
            }
            return jwt.encode(
                payload,
                app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'),
                algorithm='HS256'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return e

    @staticmethod
    def decode_auth_token(auth_token):
        """
        Validates the auth token
        :param auth_token:
        :return: integer|string
        """
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(auth_token, app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'))
            is_blacklisted_token = BlacklistToken.check_blacklist(auth_token)
            if is_blacklisted_token:
                return 'Token blacklisted. Please log in again.'
            else:
                return payload['sub']
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return 'Signature expired. Please log in again.'
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return 'Invalid token. Please log in again.'


class BlacklistToken(db.Model):
    """
    Token Model for storing JWT tokens

    """
    __tablename__ = 'blacklist_tokens'
   # __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    token = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True, nullable=False)
    blacklisted_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.blacklisted_on = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id: token: {}'.format(self.token)

    @staticmethod
    def check_blacklist(auth_token):
        # check whether auth token has been blacklisted
        res = BlacklistToken.query.filter_by(token=str(auth_token)).first()
        if res:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

#### views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask.views import MethodView

import bcrypt, db
from apppack.models import User, BlacklistToken

auth_blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


class RegisterAPI(MethodView):
    """
    User Registration Resource

    """
    def post(self):
        # get the post data
        post_data = request.get_json()
        # check if user already exists
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=post_data.get('email')).all()
        if not user:
            try:
                user = User(
                    email=post_data.get('email'),
                    password=post_data.get('password')
                )
                # insert the user
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                # generate the auth token
                auth_token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'success',
                    'message': 'Successfully registered.',
                    'auth_token': auth_token.decode()
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 201
            except Exception as e:
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'fail',
                    'message': 'Some error occurred. Please try again.'
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 401
        else:
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': 'User already exists. Please Log in.',
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 202

       #-------------------------------------------------------------------- test
             
        #post_data = request.get_json()
        ## check if user already exists
        #user = User(
        #            email=post_data.get('email'),
        #            password=post_data.get('password'),
        #        )
        #        # insert the user
        #db.session.add(user)
        #db.session.commit()
        #responseObject = {
        #            'status': 'success',
        #            'message': 'Successfully registered.',
        #            'auth_token': post_data.get('email')
        #        }
        #return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 201

       #-----------------------------------------------------------------------test

class LoginAPI(MethodView):
    """
    User Login Resource
    """
    def post(self):
        # get the post data
        post_data = request.get_json()
        try:
            # fetch the user data
            user = User.query.filter_by(
                email=post_data.get('email')
            ).first()
            if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(
                user.password, post_data.get('password')
            ):
                auth_token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
                if auth_token:
                    responseObject = {
                        'status': 'success',
                        'message': 'Successfully logged in.',
                        'auth_token': auth_token.decode()
                    }
                    return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 200
            else:
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'fail',
                    'message': 'User does not exist.'
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 404
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': 'Try again'
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 500


class UserAPI(MethodView):
    """
    User Resource
    """
    def get(self):
        # get the auth token
        auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if auth_header:
            try:
                auth_token = auth_header
                #auth_token = auth_header.split(" ")[1]
            except indexerror:
                responseobject = {
                    'status': 'fail',
                    'message': 'bearer token malformed.'
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseobject)), 401
        else:
            auth_token = ''
        if auth_token:
            resp = User.decode_auth_token(auth_token)
            if not isinstance(resp, str):
                user = User.query.filter_by(id=resp).first()
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'success',
                    'data': {
                        'user_id': user.id,
                        'email': user.email,
                        'admin': user.admin,
                        'registered_on': user.registered_on
                    }
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 200
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': resp
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 401
        else:
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': 'Provide a valid auth token.'
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 401


class LogoutAPI(MethodView):
    """
    Logout Resource
    """
    def post(self):
        # get auth token
        auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if auth_header:
            auth_token = auth_header
            #auth_token = auth_header.split(" ")
            #auth_token = auth_header.split(" ")[1]
        else:
            auth_token = ''
        if auth_token:
            resp = User.decode_auth_token(auth_token)
            if not isinstance(resp, str):
                # mark the token as blacklisted
                blacklist_token = BlacklistToken(token=auth_token)
                try:
                    # insert the token
                    db.session.add(blacklist_token)
                    db.session.commit()
                    responseObject = {
                        'status': 'success',
                        'message': 'Successfully logged out.'
                    }
                    return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 200
                except Exception as e:
                    responseObject = {
                        'status': 'fail',
                        'message': e
                    }
                    return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 200
            else:
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'fail',
                    'message': resp
                }
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 401
        else:
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': 'Provide a valid auth token.'
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 403

# define the API resources
registration_view = RegisterAPI.as_view('register_api')
login_view = LoginAPI.as_view('login_api')
user_view = UserAPI.as_view('user_api')
logout_view = LogoutAPI.as_view('logout_api')

# add Rules for API Endpoints
auth_blueprint.add_url_rule(
    '/auth/register',
    view_func=registration_view,
    methods=['POST']
)
auth_blueprint.add_url_rule(
    '/auth/login',
    view_func=login_view,
    methods=['POST']
)
auth_blueprint.add_url_rule(
    '/auth/status',
    view_func=user_view,
    methods=['GET']
)
auth_blueprint.add_url_rule(
    '/auth/logout',
    view_func=logout_view,
    methods=['POST']
)
```

I have tried all possible ways i know to resolve this but first the log says it cant import manage.py then when i removed it. And wanted to run the app without it and go straight to the login and register code that's what i want.

#### init.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from apppack.views import auth_blueprint

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'y\n=\xc5\xfa\nB\xb8t\n\x83\xbef\x8a\xe3\xddE\x17\x06\xc9\x96\x8ec|'
CORS(application)
app_settings = os.getenv(
    'APP_SETTINGS',
    '.config.DevelopmentConfig'
)
app.config.from_object(app_settings)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(application)
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

application.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
```

#### config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
 *** Hidden
database_name = 'confudb'
#'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost/'
#'flask_jwt_auth'

class BaseConfig:
    """Base configuration."""
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'y\n=\xc5\xfa\nB\xb8t\n\x83\xbef\x8a\xe3\xddE\x17\x06\xc9\x96\x8ec|')
    DEBUG = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 13
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Development configuration."""
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 4
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = postgres_local_base + database_name


class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Testing configuration."""
   # DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 4
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = postgres_local_base
    PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Production configuration."""
    SECRET_KEY = 'y\n=\xc5\xfa\nB\xb8t\n\x83\xbef\x8a\xe3\xddE\x17\x06\xc9\x96\x8ec|'
    DEBUG = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ** hidden
```

If someone can help me rectify the issue so, I can simply fix the configuration or code to run directly into the views and models and run a simple auth API on AWS Beanstalk.

Thanks

Comment: seems like you importing wrong class from the `models` in your `application.py`.

Comment: @PS1212 hey so what to import in order to run?

Comment: bro change and delete actual database credentials  from your code.

Comment: Done, can you help?

Comment: @saif-ali which `flask` version are you using?

Comment: @PS1212 Kindly please help me out, I'm using the latest 1.0.2 and Python3